# Biztalk REST API issue

Tags: rest, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I call a REST API which return a JSON message that is validated on the receive pipeline with JSON decoder (schema + namespace). This API can return also a response containing a "null" string message with a 200 HTTP status.

Is there a way to tell to the receive pipeline to expect these 2 different schemas? For information the API is called from a wcf-HTTP send port within an orchestration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess also use an interceptor message custom behavior and modify the message content to empty if message ="null" so the new json decoder pipeline will add  "{}" as body regarding the new hotfix "Add message body for empty message".